# Serve Angular inside URI, with /assets folder

Tags: angular, nginx

i'm struggling a bit with serving angular with nginx.
The thing is, in the base URI there's an api, which nginx proxy-passes the requests to.
Then behind a URI "/interface" it's loading everything except the "assets" folder. Because it seems it's now well-referenced.

The command i use to build the angular webpage is:

```sh
RUN ng build --configuration=dev --output-path=dist --base-href=/interface/
```

And my nginx config is:

```
location /interface {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /interface/index.html;
}
```

And my output is like so:

[image]

### This `assets` folders is messing it up.

edit 1:
NGINX LOGS_>

```
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:43 +0000] "GET /interface HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:43 +0000] "GET /interface/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1218 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /interface/styles.32540aa30747f5274629.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /interface/polyfills-es2015.ffa9bb4e015925544f91.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /interface/main-es2015.1d67bcd1e0c93a4ef3b3.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /interface/runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /assets/i18n/en.json HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 2020/11/10 12:01:44 [error] 95#95: *92 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.28, server: windtec.nexusgeografics.com, request: "GET /assets/i18n/en.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.54:8000/assets/i18n/en.json", host: "192.168.0.54", referrer: "https://192.168.0.54/interface/"
nginx      | 2020/11/10 12:01:44 [error] 95#95: *92 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.28, server: windtec.nexusgeografics.com, request: "GET /assets/img/logo%20(1)@2x.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.54:8000/assets/img/logo%20(1)@2x.png", host: "192.168.0.54", referrer: "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /assets/img/logo%20(1)@2x.png HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /assets/img/Grupo%2042.svg HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /assets/img/Grupo%2043.svg HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 2020/11/10 12:01:44 [error] 95#95: *92 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.28, server: windtec.nexusgeografics.com, request: "GET /assets/img/Grupo%2042.svg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.54:8000/assets/img/Grupo%2042.svg", host: "192.168.0.54", referrer: "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login"
nginx      | 2020/11/10 12:01:44 [error] 95#95: *93 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.28, server: windtec.nexusgeografics.com, request: "GET /assets/img/Grupo%2043.svg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.54:8000/assets/img/Grupo%2043.svg", host: "192.168.0.54", referrer: "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /interface/fons_login.f065d97fdb8c6cd8da06.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
nginx      | 192.168.0.28 - - [10/Nov/2020:12:01:44 +0000] "GET /interface/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 948 "https://192.168.0.54/interface/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
```

Comment: Could you please provide your nginx log file?

Comment: done. u see the connection failed, because it's getting uri from root path, and there will be an API.